# What does Laptop Mode do?

Tags: ape-out

In the options menu of Ape Out there's a setting to turn Laptop Mode on or off. What does the "Laptop Mode" option do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Ape Out v1.1 patch notes](https://store.steampowered.com/news/app/447150/view/5315892737484204802), Laptop Mode removes some visual effects to improve performance.